# Getting a segmentation fault when adding a piece of code that is working correctly

Tags: c, pointers, reference, segmentation-fault

I'm new to C, and I have these basic functions, like swap and read_int. Read_int is supposed to receive a char that is in fact a number between 0 and 9, and return its numerical value.

Those functions seem to work.

Here's the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(int *adra, int *adrb){
    int tmp = *adra;
    *adra = *adrb;
    *adrb = tmp;
}

int read_int(int *adr){
    printf("Entrer une suite d'entier entre 0 et 9.\n");
    char c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n'){
        if ( c >= 48 && c <= 57){
            *adr = *adr + c - 49;
            c = getchar();
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}


int main(){
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    swap(&a,&b);
    printf("%d\n",a);
    printf("%d\n",b);

    char c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n'){
        printf("Le caractere ’%c’ est en fait le nombre %d\n",c,c);
        c = getchar();
    }

    int *test;
    printf("read_int = %d\n",read_int(test));
    printf("test = %d\n",*test);

    /*int tab[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int *pi = tab;
    short *ps = (short *) tab;
    char *pc = (char *) tab;
    printf("int : %p %p\n",pi,pi+1);
    printf("short : %p %p\n",ps,ps+1);
    printf("char : %p %p\n",pc,pc+1);
    printf("%ld\n",(long)(&pi[1]-&pi[0]));
    printf("%ld\n",(long)(&ps[1]-&ps[0]));
    printf("%ld\n",(long)(&pc[1]-&pc[0]));*/

    return 1;
}
```

The results with this code is this:

```
3
2
2
Le caractere ’2’ est en fait le nombre 50
Entrer une suite d'entier entre 0 et 9.
2
read_int = 1
test = 2
```

For me, it's the expected result.

But then when I uncomment the last block of code in the main, this is the output I'm getting:

```
3
2
1
Le caractere ’1’ est en fait le nombre 49
Entrer une suite d'entier entre 0 et 9.
1
[1]    3960 segmentation fault
```

I don't get why the last block which has nothing to do with what I have written above it can provoke a segmentation fault. Especially when I tried it in another file and that it worked perfectly.

Any leads please?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try `int test;` and `read_int(&test)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int *test;` is not initialized before calling `read_int()`. It means that when you try to access the location with `*adr = *adr + c - 49;` you are in big trouble (== undefined behavior)! What is the value of `addr`? What is the initial value of `*addr`?

You must initialize it to point to a valid variable. You can simply declare an `int` and pass its address to the function:

```
int value = 0;
read_int(&value);
```

With an explicit pointer, this is equivalent to:

```
int value = 0;
int* addr = &value;
read_int(addr);
```

Comment: Great! By the way: because a program seems to work, it doesn't mean it is error-free. Specially in C. Your code here is a proof. Don't forget to activate warnings from the compiler (eg: -Wall -Wextra options with gcc and clang).

Answer (score 1):

You are passing to read_int() an uninitialized pointer.

```
    int *test;  // test should contain the address of an integer
    printf("read_int = %d\n",read_int(test));
    printf("test = %d\n",*test);
```

If you try to write at an invalid address, segmentation fault is waht you get.

Try instead

```
    int test;
    printf("read_int = %d\n",read_int(&test));
    printf("test = %d\n",test);
```

In this way you pass to the funtion the address of `test` loacl variable, that is for sure valid, and print it by value.

In order to use a pointer, you should dynamically allocate it:

```
    int *test = malloc( sizeof(int));
    printf("read_int = %d\n",read_int(test));
    printf("test = %d\n",*test);
    free(test);
```